# find coefficient of $x^{50}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, combinations

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)}$then find the coefficient of term $x^{50}$ in $(f(x))^3$.I think that we can set $$(f(x))^3=\frac{a}{(1+x)^3}+\frac{b}{(1+x^2)^3}+\frac{c}{(1+x^4)^3}$$ and find a,b and c then use Taylor seri .

Comment: that is indeed one possible way to get the result

Comment: this looks like a generating function for integer compositions into three parts. is that what you are working from?

Comment: Or you can multiply numerator and denominator by $1-x$

Comment: $(1-x)^{3}*(1-x^8)^{-3}$ , if you know binomial theorem for negative exponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^8}=(1-x)(1-x^8)^{-1}$ if $|x^8|<1$.

Now note that when $|x|<1$ then \begin{align*}
(1-x)^{-1}=&\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}x^n\\
-(1-x)^{-2}=&\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}nx^{n-1}\\
+2(1-x)^{-3}=&\sum\limits_{n\geq 2}n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}\\
(1-x)^{-3}=&\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}x^{n}
\end{align*}
which means $f(x)^3=(1-x)^3(1-x^8)^{-3}=(1-3x+3x^2-x^3)\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}x^{8n}$

On the RHS, we have the terms of the forms $x^{8n}, x^{8n+1}, x^{8n+2}, x^{8n+3}$. Since none of $8n, 8n+1, 8n+3$ but $8n+2$ provide 50 (for $n=6$) so the required coefficient of $x^{50}$ is $3\frac{8.7}{2}=84$

Comment: I don't know but how did you get so many combinations shouldn't infinite series have powers of $x^8$? that means $x^{48}$ can be only option for having multiplication.

Comment: upppsss...I am extremely sorry for my typo. Please give me little time. I will fix it @Mann

Comment: Haha, happens. ^^

Comment: Thanks for rectifying my mistake. Just fix it. :-) \

Answer (score 1):

It won't work like that: $f(x)^3 = \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^3 (1+x^2)^3 (1+x^4)^3}$, and then the partial-fraction expansion will include terms in $1/(1+x)$, $1/(1+x)^2$, ...